# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED request.get

Tags: python

I am trying to download [this url](https://tips.danskespil.dk/tips13/?#/tps/poolid/2954) which is a frame on [this](https://danskespil.dk/tips#/tps/poolid/2954) page.

I have tried like this:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://tips.danskespil.dk/tips13/?#/tps/poolid/2954'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
```

and also this way:

```
import requests
page = requests.get(url)
```

but both ways give me the error: `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED request.get`

Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: come on, dude! this question has been asked a million times here.

Comment: My bad - you're wright it is a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not worried about safety (which you should be) your best bet is to use `verify=False` in the request function.

```
page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

You can also set `verify` to a directory of certificates with trusted CAs like so

`verify = '/path/to/certfile'`

You can refer to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) here for all the ways to get around it

Comment: This is a very wrong advice to give.

Comment: Brilliant - thx. What would be my security concern? - I am asking out of ignorance